# No operator "==" maches these operands

Tags: c++

so I try to compare iterator value that I get from it->second with int to get the key from map on the base of the value. I have this code :

```
std::map<string, std::vector<int> >::const_iterator it;
void getStudentByGrade(int gradeComp)
{
    for (it = studMap.begin(); it != studMap.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->second == gradeComp)
        {
            cout << it->first;
        }
    }
}
```

and in the if statement I get the error , but I compare two ints don't I ?? The int that is passed as gradeComp and the it->second.

The error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'const std::vector>' (or there
>   is no acceptable conversion)

How to solve the error ? I found examples of getting to key with value only with iterator.

Comment: `it->second` is a `std::vector<int>`, innit.

Comment: Addition to first comment, you might want to make a change `std::map<string, int>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I compare two ints don't I??

No you do not. Look:

```
it->second == gradeComp
```

Since `it` is an (const) iterator to `std::map<string, std::vector<int>>`, `it->second` has type `std::vector<int> const&`. On the other hand, `gradeComp` is an `int`. This is why your compiler tells you

> No operator “==” maches these operands

those operands being a vector of integers and an integer.

---

> How to solve the error?

Well, it depends on what you mean. Do you mean to *search* `gradeComp` in the vector? Or maybe you mean to compare it with a specific value from the vector?

```
// is gradeComp contained in the found vector?
if (end(it->second) != std::find(begin(it->second), end(it->second), gradeComp))
{ /* ... */ }

// does gradeComp match n-th value of vector?
if (gradeComp  == it->second[n])
{ /* ... */ }
```